# Unable to set Log On As when creating a service with SVCCTL CreateServiceW

Tags: java, jcifs

I'm using the SVCCTL CreateServiceW method to remotely install a service, and I have this working. I have since discovered that I need to set the "Log On As" account and I can't seem to make this work.

I have noticed that the CreateServiceW defines the information relevant to the log on as user with:

```
public String lpServiceStartName;
public byte[] password;
public int password_size;
```

(with the encoding processing as

```
        _dst.enc_ndr_referent(lpServiceStartName, 1);
        if (lpServiceStartName != null) {
            _dst.enc_ndr_string(lpServiceStartName);

        }
        _dst.enc_ndr_referent(password, 1);
        if (password != null) {
            int _passwords = password_size;
            _dst.enc_ndr_long(_passwords);
            int _passwordi = _dst.index;
            _dst.advance(1 * _passwords);

            _dst = _dst.derive(_passwordi);
            for (int _i = 0; _i < _passwords; _i++) {
                _dst.enc_ndr_small(password[_i]);
            }
        }
        _dst.enc_ndr_long(password_size);
```

)

(all from https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/download/attachments/15007754/svcctl.java?version=1&modificationDate=1331544065000&api=v2)

My question is "what should I be placing in the password element?".

-Thanks
-Mark

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. Doing other research online, it seems the common consensus is to send UTF-16LE encoded string, for the password. But, that seems to cause the service to fail creation. I can create the service if I set the username, but leave the password null with 0 length. How do we know what format windows wants this password, for setting the log on section of the service?

Or, is it possible that the referenced code above is not the proper way to set the password? I.E. write the size/length, then write the password, then write the size/length again.